# Article about science fiction languages

Tags: story-identification, languages

I'm looking for a journal item, probably written between 1992 and 1994, which discusses languages from Venus on the Half-Shell, Sagan's Contact, and several other novels, usually science fiction, containing "made up" languages.  I got the books and cannot find the article; it is not in the book Aliens and Science Fiction.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/From-Elvish-Klingon-Exploring-Languages/dp/0192807099 ?

Comment: I do not know the article you are talking about. However, this website has much of the information that you may want from such an article:

http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/futurelang.php

Furthermore, the page has many reference links. One of these might point to the article you want.

Comment: You might be interested in the "Linguistics in SF" section of [this blog](http://tenser.typepad.com/tenser_said_the_tensor/2004/03/a_word_of_expla.html).

Comment: Any idea in which journal you might have come across it?

Comment: There have been many articles written in constructed languages in science fiction. You'll really have to give more than that.

Comment: In case it helps, a wealth of resources, links etc at http://www.joerg-rhiemeier.de/Conlang/